# Is it possible to send notification from one phone to another using firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I send a notification directly from one android phone to another using firebase messaging?

(I don't have a separate backend server)

Comment: 1) FCM should already provide this 2) if not, Google Cloud Functions does exactly this

Comment: I am not familiar with JS, so cloud functions is not the solution right now. Do you know any other method ? I can't find a way to do it with fcm

Comment: And how long did you search the Internet, really? "send notifications between android devices on Firebase" got this... http://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html and it specifically calls out Cloud functions

Comment: It was just released this month, so it's new, and unfortunately you must use the Node.js API

Comment: Thanks for the replies. but don't know JS enough!

Comment: Check out the tutorials that's linked in the post. You don't need to know JS, just need to learn how to read the API to get what you want. The only other way to get what you're asking for is to setup your own push server (and that'll take longer than JS code)